# Responsive top navigation – reposition links using divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to html/css and I have been following this guide to create a responsive header with a dropdown menu: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp

I want to know if it is possible to reposition the links like in the article when the viewport is small if the links are separated inside different divs, one div containing the home link and the other div containing the rest of the links plus the dropdown div and its contents.

So I attempted that and got it halfway working in that when small links will disappear and the hamburger menu icon will appear. The problem is when small and clicking the icon the links are not displaying underneath the navigation or the home link like it is in the article. Two links are still displaying beside “Home” and are inaccessible, dropdown seems fine and the last link also seems fine. I’m uncertain as to how to properly style this.

I understand using a framework would be much easier, but since I’m new I thought maybe I should try this with only html/css/javascript.

Any help or direction is appreciated, thanks!

Example of what I want to make using the divs when viewport is small if possible:
[Link to what I want cause I can't post pictures yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgNbR.png)

[What happens instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II6ty.png)

Below is what code I have. Changes I made from the original are wrapping the home link and other links into separate divs and some positions I left as fixed because I wanted the navigation bar to move with scrolling. I also changed the dropdown method to on click because I don’t think mobiles have a way to hover.

If it helps, I think the issue is with the CSS where I add the styles for the "responsive" class.

```js
function responsiveLinks() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
} 


/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function clickDropdown() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body, html {
      height:100%;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-transform:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 32px;
}    
.topnav {
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position to scroll */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  background-color: #333;
  z-index:1;
}    
.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px; 
  float: left;
}    

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}    
/*Style the dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}    
/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}    
/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}    
/* Add a background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}    
/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.show {display:block;} /* For use with clickDropdow() */

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide the links div and its contents. Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .links {
    display: none;  /*Changed to work with the divs, hides the whole links div*/
  }    
  .topnav a.icon {
    background: inherit;
    float:right;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
 

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .links{
    background:grey;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
   }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: in-line;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Page</title> 
</head>
<body> 
 <div class="topnav"  id="myTopnav">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="home.html"><img src="" width="50" height="50" alt="Home"/></a>
   </div> <!-- end logo -->
 <div class="links">
 <a href="#news">News</a>
 <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="clickDropdown()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div><!-- end dropdown contents -->
  </div><!-- end dropdown -->
 <a href="#about">About</a>
</div><!-- end links -->
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="responsiveLinks()">&#9776;</a>
</div> <!-- end topnap -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please show us the screenshot of what you want. thanks

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of what I'm after

Comment: what changes hav you done man.. if use the same code from the link then it is working fine.

Comment: I put the home link in its own div and and the rest of the links + the dropdown in another div. I wanted to know if it can be done that way instead and I'm having issues. I'll post a pic of what goes wrong

Comment: i have added an answer. please check tell me what else you want

Answer (score 0):

i have put the logo inplace of `Home`. hope this helps. tell me what else you want.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active"><img src="" width="50" height="50" alt="Home"/></a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

**please try this code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:Arial;
}    
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}    
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}    
.active {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: white;
}    
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}    
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}    
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}    
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}    
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}    
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}    
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}    
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}    
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}    
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
   }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>    
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>    
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```